# Is there a way to determine if a redis key contains a list or a set?

Tags: ruby, redis

After determining the list of keys in a redis database, is there any way to determine if a particular key (given only the name) is a list or a set?

I am using the Ruby redis gem 2.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the TYPE command.

r.type(:mykey)